# Public key to apply digital signing in iText

Tags: itext, digital-signature

Is it possible to use public key to apply digital signing and verifying the signatures through private key in PDF using iText?

Comment: What do you try to achieve? As Eugene mentioned in his answer, using some other person's public key generally only makes sense if you want to encrypt information only the holder of the private key shall be able to decrypt. That being said, the new iText signing API has become very flexible and allows you to easily create signature containers externally. Thus,merely implement your cms creation scheme to "sign" using a public key and let iText do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Signing is done using private keys and verification is done using public key. The opposite scheme usually constitutes encryption (you encrypt data using public key and decrypt it using private key).